# Multilevel Mediation in Lavaan, centering of variables

Tags: centering, r-lavaan, multilevel-analysis

I want to perform Multilevel Mediation Analyses in R with Lavaan, but I came across a Problem:

Normally, at least that is what I've learned, it is important to group-mean center level-1 variables and grand-mean center level-2 variables for multilevel analyses. So that's what I did when trying to do multilevel mediation in lavaan as well.

Not surprising, I got tons of errors when first trying, but after lots of troubleshooting, I simply went for the non-centered variables and it worked perfectly. The outcomes also seem to be very similar to what I get for the different paths in my centered multilevel regressions.

So my question is: **Is it not necessary to do group/grand-mean centering for multilevel mediation analyses in lavaan** (maybe because Lavaan does the centering itself by default)?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Hey Sebastian, you may be better off with this question on CrossValidated, because it is more about statistics than coding. I have no direct answer for you because I have never used Lavaan for multilevel stuff (it is very new, isn't it?) but I have done multilevel mediations based on bootstrapped indirect effects (a*b paths) from multilevel regressions. Let me know if you want to go that way instead. Funny coincidence meeting you here btw ;)

Comment: Hi Beni! Nice to "see" you here. ;) I'm not sure how new it is to be able to perform Multilevel Mediations in lavaan, but I've already gotten an answer elsewhere. It appears that lavaan does indeed have a built-in default that takes care of this. Greetings from Germany, Sebastian